# What is the game in the screenshot?

Tags: game-identification

I found a screenshot of a game I really want to play, it looks fun! Can anybody help me find out where it is from?

[image]

This game is similar to games like uniwar and polytopia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to be a mobile game called Dominus, which describes itself as:

> A free multiplayer social strategy game.
>
> Grow in power by conquering castles. Gain vassals until you can
> overthrow your lord and climb the tree to become the Dominus.
>
> Dominus is a slow strategy game. Army movement and resource gathering
> happen slowly over time. Login, give your armies their orders then
> check back in a few hours. Chat with other players to form alliances
> and conquer larger enemies.

The screenshot on their home page (https://dominusgame.net/) seems to confirm this.

[image: dominus_game_homepage_screenshot]